# Why does gcc think that I am trying to make a function call in my template function signature?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

GCC seem to think that I am trying to make a function call in my template function signature. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the following?

```
227 template<class edgeDecor, class vertexDecor, bool dir>
228 vector<Vertex<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir>> Graph<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir>::vertices()
229 {
230 return V;
231 };
```

GCC is giving the following:

```
graph.h:228: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
graph.h:228: error: template argument 3 is invalid
graph.h:228: error: template argument 1 is invalid
graph.h:228: error: template argument 2 is invalid
graph.h:229: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should put space between two `>`. `>>` is parsed as a bit-shift operator, not two closing brackets.

Comment: Note that this will no longer be necessary in C++0x or whatever they decide to call the final standard

Comment: @JB: C++11 from the latest Herb Sutter's column :)

Comment: @Matthieu: Effectively he said that, if all goes well, we *should* end up with C++11. But it seems its spreading already.

Comment: Of course it is! We've been waiting for so long that his announce was bound to be taken at face value ;) Though I'll kind of miss the `0x`, it was neat I think, kind of futurist.